# Authentication against Azure AD tenant for my own WebAPI

Tags: javascript, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, outlook

I have a problem to understand whether the various Authentication samples I find in the interwebs apply to my really simple use case, and how to get an OAuth Implicit authentication flow to work reliably cross-browser.

**The requirements**

I have a (non-Angular) single-page intranet app (SPA) for a single Azure AD tenant (the tenant is configurable during setup). The app runs against a .NET WebAPI backend in an authenticated fashion. **I don't need to access other servers on behalf of the logged-in user, the WebAPI backend only needs to know for himself who sits in front of the SPA on the client.** (This should be the easiest scenario of all.)

That auth process has to run reliably in all browsers on Windows, as well as embedded in Outlook (JS add-in), even if the auth flow of the Azure AD is forced through local ADFS and/or MFA and/or other hoops, and the auth process has to work around browser features like popup blockers. Also, the app may not require re-authentication every hour, like it does right now.

I would prefer that these hard requirements should be achievable using standard authentication processes, not through a fully self-written authentication. **However, after tries with various OAuth client libraries, self-written auth looks like the only possible approach right now.**

**What I did**

First, I added Azure AD Bearer authentication to the WebAPI:

```
WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions windowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Audience = clientId,
    Tenant = tenantId
};
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(windowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions);
```

Then, I included [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) into my SPA and tried to get the login with a popup and the access token through a hidden iframe:

```
settings: {
    tenant: '09265c06-fa36-4a7a-90cd-e3c2b0dd1c39',
    clientId: '16f66ef5-e30a-4e22-b191-3f230ef8d93c',
    popUp:true
},
acquireLogin: function() {
    var me = this,
        pollForLoginCallback = function() {
            var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
                var token = me.AuthContext.getCachedToken(me.settings.clientId);
                if(token) { // We wait until a token has been returned
                    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                    me.acquireToken();
                }
            },50);
        };
    pollForLoginCallback();
    me.AuthContext.login();
},
acquireToken: function() {
    var me = this;
    // After login, we try to acquire the required tokens. This is necessary to get a token that can be refreshed in the background.
    me.AuthContext.getCachedUser(); // we don't need the user here, but acquireToken fails if getCachedUser is not executed before.
    me.tokenRefreshInProgress = true;
    me.AuthContext.acquireToken(me.settings.clientId, function (error, token) {
        if(!token) me.acquireLogin();
        else {
            me.tokenRefreshInProgress = false;
            me.successCallback(token);
        }
    });
},
successCallback:function(token) {
    // Apply token to all future Ajax requests.
    Ext.Ajax.setDefaultHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    });
    // Load Settings from Server.
    me.loadSettings();
}
```

I got the initial authentication with a popup working in the easiest case (Chrome and Firefox with popup blocker disabled), but Microsoft's own browsers always require special security settings to work at all (are stuck in an endless authentication loop otherwise), and the Outlook add-in does not allow `window.open` at all.

Furthermore, the refresh in the hidden iframe fails regularly, presumably because the refresh token is not correctly received/stored, and then, the "initial login" has to pop up again.

So for the Outlook add-in, however, I have to set `popUp: false` in ADAL.js, which means that when the re-login is due, the whole page is reloaded and loops through the authentication process again, and the user may lose data he just entered.

I also tried the Office-js-helpers library, which is far easier to implement than ADAL.js and works similarly well in Chrome:

```
me.Authenticator = new OfficeHelpers.Authenticator();
me.Authenticator.endpoints.registerAzureADAuth(settings.clientId, settings.tenant, {
    responseType: 'id_token',
    redirectUrl: window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
});
me.Authenticator
.authenticate(OfficeHelpers.DefaultEndpoints.AzureAD)
.then(function (token) {
    me.successCallback(token.id_token);
})
.catch(OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log);
```

but in Outlook, for which it was initially written, it cannot even open the dialog window ([I already submitted a bug report for that](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/issues/52)).

Also, the "pure" Office.js library/API has the possibility to get two different tokens ([`getUserIdentityTokenAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.1/Office.context.mailbox#getuseridentitytokenasynccallback-usercontext) and [`getCallbackTokenAsync`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.1/Office.context.mailbox#getcallbacktokenasynccallback-usercontext)), but no possibility to get a token accepted by my application. I have checked the token and found that the "Audience" on these tokens is a constant GUID that represents the original Office 365 and the Microsoft Graph, respectively. So, just out of curiosity, I have told my backend to accept the Office365 Audience as well:

```
WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions windowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions2 = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Audience = "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", // CONST Outlook/Exchange clientId
    Tenant = tenantId
};
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(windowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions2);
```

but when I submitted the Outlook token with that audience to the backend, it still returned Error 401.

So now I'm completely and utterly stuck with three Microsoft libraries that seem to only have half of their advertised features in half of the browsers; and really, **all I need is reliable authentication for my backend.** Nothing fancy.

**Workaround: Implement my own auth**

The only way through the jungle right now is to implement my own old-school authentication directly in the SPA, using a username/password form, sending the username/password to a WebAPI controller that does a password check against AD Graph or EWS, and if successful, sends a cookie (valid for at least one day) to the client.

**However**, this cannot be the final result of all that OAuth flow, or is it?

**So, my question is:** How can I find my way through the OAuth authentication flow jungle in a cross-browser fashion, with Outlook 2016 add-in compatibility?

Comment: Is the security zone same for the domain of your app and `https://login.microsoftonline.com`? If not, is it helpful to set the in a same secure zone for example like **Trusted Sites** for the refresh token issue? The root cause for this issue is that IE may not find the cookie when the request is from different security zone with the orignal page.

Comment: Yes, the security zone is the same. Otherwise, the first login already fails.

Comment: This first login should not fail when they are in the different security zone because the user-info is returned by the id_token passed using URL or HTML body. Refer detail about this issue from [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/10/beware-cookie-sharing-in-cross-zone-scenarios/). I suggest that you capture the detailed error message for the token refreshing.